# How to create char array of letters from a string array ? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

For example, I have a `string`:

> "Nice to meet you"

, there are 13 letters when we count repeating letters, but I wanna create a `char` `array` of letters from this string without repeating letters, I mean for the string above it should create an `array` like

`{'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', 't', 'o', 'y', 'u', 'm'}`

I was looking for answers on google for 2 hours, but I found nothing, there were lots of answers about strings and char arrays, but were not answers for my situation. I thought that I can write code by checking every letter in the array by 2 `for` cycles but this time I got syntax errors, so I decided to ask.

Comment: We may help you with those syntax errors, *if* you provide your code

Comment: 'N' is different from 'n'?

Comment: use hashset https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0 `The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am not sure about my code cuz I had no chance to verify this code because of syntax errors, so I thought that maybe my algorithm is not correct and asked for a direct answer

Comment: If this is homework, then you are maybe not allowed to use the Linq-based answers

Comment: No, it is not homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var foo = "Nice to meet you";
var fooArr = s.ToCharArray();
HashSet<char> set = new();
set.UnionWith(fooArr);

//or if you want without whitespaces you could refactor this as below
set.UnionWith(fooArr.Where(c => c != ' '));
```

**UPDATE**:
You could even make an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> ToUniqueCharArray(this string source, char? ignoreChar)
{
     var charArray = source.ToCharArray();
     HashSet<char> set = new();
     set.UnionWith(charArray.Where(c => c != ignoreChar));
     return set;
}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
var foo = "Nice to meet you";
var uniqueChars = foo.ToUniqueCharArray(ignoreChar: ' ');

// if you want to keep the whitespace
var uniqueChars = foo.ToUniqueCharArray(ignoreChar: null);
```

Answer (score 2):

this piece of code does the job:

```
var sentence = "Nice To meet you";
var arr = sentence.ToLower().Where(x => x !=' ' ).ToHashSet();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr));
```

I have added `ToLower()` if you dont do differences between uppercase and lowercase, if case is sensitive you just put off this extension..
HashSet suppresses all duplicates letters

test: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f58oc1)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this one and it works too

```
"Nice to meet you".Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray().Distinct();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You don't really need ToCharArray - a string is already an `IEnumerable<char>`. But you may need an additional `.ToArray()` at the end, to make the result an array

Answer (score 2):

A very short solution is to use [`.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) on the input string:

```csharp
string text = "Nice to meet you";

char[] letters = text.Except(" ").ToArray();
```

Here, `.Except()`:

1. translates both the text string and the parameter string (`" "`) to char collections
2. filters out all the chars in the text char collection that are present in the parameter char collection
3. returns a collection of distinct chars from the filtered text char collection

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFQeSO).

---

###### Visualizing the process

Let's use the blue banana as an example.

```csharp
var input = "blue banana";
```

1. `input.Except(" ")` will be translated to:

```csharp
{ 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a' }.Except({ ' ' })
```

2. Filtering out all `' '` occurrences in the text char array produces:

```csharp
{ 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a' }
```

3. The distinct char collection will have all the duplicates of `'b'`, `'a'` and `'n'` removed, resulting in:

```csharp
{ 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'a', 'n' }
```

Comment: I like this answer; the interesting (and at first sight not so obvious) thing here is that `Except` is a *set operation* which ensures that duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 1):

A solution just using for-loops (no generics or Linq), with comments explaining things:

```cs
// get rid of the spaces
String str = "Nice to meet you".Replace(" ", "");

// a temporary array more than long enough (we will trim it later)
char[] temp = new char[str.Length];

// the index where to insert the next char into "temp". This is also the length of the filled-in part
var idx = 0;

// loop through the source string
for (int i=0; i<str.Length; i++)
{
    // get the character at this position (NB "surrogate pairs" will fail here)
    var c = str[i];
    
    // did we find it in the following loop?
    var found = false;

    // loop through the collected characters to see if we already have it
    for (int j=0; j<idx; j++)
    {
        if (temp[j] == c)
        {
            // yes, we already have it!
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!found)
    {
        // we didn't already have it, so add
        temp[idx] = c;
        idx+=1;
    }
}

// "temp" is too long, so create a new array of the correct size
var letters = new char[idx];
Array.Copy(temp, letters, idx);
// now "letters" contains the unique letters
```

That "surrogate pairs" remark basically means that emojis will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str  = "Nice To meet you";
char[] letters = str.ToLower().Except(" ").ToArray();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See the [answer by Astrid E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71450107/121309) to see *why* "Except" works